# Set a cookie on first time page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, jquery-cookie

How can I set a cookie via jQuery cookie (`$.cookie()`) library, only when the page is loaded for the first time? I currently have a toggle feature, to change the value of the cookie in question upon a `click` event

```
$('.family-filter').click(function() {
    if ($.cookie('ff') == null) {
        $.cookie('ff', 'on', {
            expires: 1,
            path: '/'
        });
    } else {
        $.cookie('ff', null, {
            path: '/'
        });
    }
});
```

But I need a default value, if none is set already.

Also happy to set it via PHP, but I'd prefer for this case, to do it via Javascript

Comment: You want to set the cookie on CLICK or on LOAD? You're clearly setting the cookie on click. $.ready for on page load.

Comment: I don't think you need the `else if`. Checking if it is null and then creating it should be enough

Comment: yea, the `else if` not needed... I forgot to take it out. The `else` is needed to set it off by link if is on and vice versa. @MatBee, I've tried setting it on `$.ready` but I ended overwriting the code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I decided to implement it this way:

```
if ($.cookie('ff') == null) {
    $.cookie('ff', 'on', {
        expires: 30,
        path: '/'
    });
}

$('.family-filter').click(function() {
    if ($.cookie('ff') == 'off') {
        $.cookie('ff', 'on', {
            expires: 30,
            path: '/'
        });
    } else {
        $.cookie('ff', 'off', {
            path: '/'
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

In page load you can set this code to check and set cookies

```
<?php

if (!isset($_COOKIE["ff"])) {
    // Expire Time is 30 Days
    $expire = time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 30;
    setcookie('ff', 'on', $expire);
}
```

Comment: yea, I could do so in the home controller in codeginiter... I will try

Answer (score 2):

I'm adding a cokkie like so:

```
if (document.cookie.indexOf('visited=true') == -1) {
    var thirtydays = 1000*60*60*24*30;
    var expires = new Date((new Date()).valueOf() +  thirtydays);
    document.cookie = "visited=true;expires=" +  expires.toUTCString();
}
```

It works fine for me, and you can add some more code inside the `if` clause if you need something to run while the user it's on his first visit on the website.

Comment: thanks for the info, but for now I am trying to set the cookie inside my home controller in codeigniter http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9069521/cant-set-cookie-inside-construct-in-codeigniter