# Can't set cookie inside construct in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies, constructor, setcookie

I trying to set a cookie if `null` but I can't get it to work:

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    if ($this->input->cookie('ff', TRUE) == FALSE)
    {
        $this->input->set_cookie('ff', 'on', 86500);
        dump($this->input->cookie('ff', TRUE));
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:
`dump()` it's just a custom debug function.

Comment: What does `dump()` do? Cookies need to be set before anything else is sent to the browser as they are in the response headers. http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Comment: dump is a custom debug function. Then how can I properly set in codeigniter a cookie if empty?

Comment: You can use a number of ways to debug without affecting the ability to set headers. You can use Firebug with FirePHP, email yourself the output with `mail()` or write to a log file or use PHPs output buffering. Additionally in this case you could just put your call to `dump()` after you have set the cookie.

Comment: the `dump()` function isn't the problem, I've tried all sorts of things... the cookie just won't set. It should give no problems when setting a cookie in construct, right?

Answer (score 2):

A couple of reasons your set_cookie call might fail:

1) You've output something to the browser already when set_cookie is called, in which case you might get an error/notice along the lines of "Headers already sent".  To fix that, just ensure that the set_cookie call occurs before sending anything to the browser.

2) If you're doing local development and testing, "localhost" is not considered a valid domain, so no cookies will be saved for it.  A workaround would be to add an entry in your hosts file, for example:

```
localhost.dev    127.0.0.1
```

And then test with that domain, instead of "localhost".